# Why do If Statement with Scanner Keep Looping

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I have this method in my subclass:

```
public void displayOptions()
{
    System.out.println("Sportscar driving options");
     if (isOverheated())
         System.out.println("WARNING: car is overheated.");
     System.out.println("(c)ool off");
     System.out.println("(d)rive normally");
     System.out.println("(q)uit simulation");
     System.out.print("Enter selection: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     String optionc = scanner.nextLine();
     if (optionc.equals("c")){
        System.out.println("all sport");
     }
     if (optionc.equals("d")) {
        System.out.println("normal drive");
     }
     if (optionc.equals("q")) {
        System.out.println("qutting simulation");
        System.exit(0);
        System.out.println("qutting simulation");

     }
     this.displayOptions();
}
```

and this in my main method:

```
    System.out.println("=== Sports car driving options ===");
    Sports sportcar = new Sports((char) 0, null);
    sportcar.displayOptions();
    System.out.println("Move: ");
    System.out.println("Sports: ");
```

As you can see it never gets to the Move: and Sports: system.out.print lines because it keeps looping this even after I input it:

```
Sportscar driving options
(c)ool off
(d)rive normally
(q)uit simulation
Enter selection:
```

So my question is, how would I stop this code from being stuck in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

`displayOptions()` calls `displayOptions()` at the last line, which calls `displayOptions()` and so on ad infinitum.

Comment: Strange, because I have another subclass I called SUV, which I called the exact same way in my main method `truck.displayOptions();` and it only takes input once and goes to the next print statement